# Einstein bot : returning custom fields from Knowledge

Tags: knowledge, chat, einstein-bots

I'm trying to Set up Object Search to find articles related to a customer question in Einstein Bots.

The search works well but for some reason I can not surface any custom fields of the Knowledge object because they don't appear in the picklist. I created a custom chatbot user with system admin profile (for testing) and knowledge user permission. So far I was only able to add standard fields (Title, Summary,...) in the chatbot configuration.

Is this a limitation or am I missing something?

FYI: I was following this guide for setting it up: [Einstein bots cookbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_knowledge_flow.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to show the information by querying it from the knowledge article version associated with the article selected by the user.

The flow tries to query records based on {!InputKnowledgeArticle.Id}
If the decision indicates the article is found the answer is merged into a text variable and returned.

[image: Flow to query the item]

Based on the returned answer we can display the appropriate response.

[image: Steps to use the flow and display response]